# C Program to list files

Tags: c, linux

I'm creating a very simple C program call `open.c` that will either:

1) List the files in the directory that will have the files text stored in an array

I have this code so far but it doesn't seem to work.

{    }

Comment: I don't think this will even compile, because you're referring to nonexistent variables ad and ah...

Comment: dirent.h is included two times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449370/ubuntu-listing-up-files-recursively-detecting-sym-linksq

Comment: If one is not able to write a function this short that can compile, one should not be worried about how to parse directory entries.

Comment: one step further [getopt()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html)

Comment: The right compilation command should be `gcc -Wall -g open.c -o open` and you should improve your code till no warnings are given by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `argv` to compare the command-line arguments with `"-ah"` and `"-ad"`.

```
#include <string.h>

if (argc > 2)
{
  if (strcmp (argv[1], "-ah") == 0)
  {
    /* List hidden files */
  }
  else if (strcmp (argv[1], "-ad") == 0)
  {
    /* List files */
  }
  else
  {
    /* Unknown command-line argument */
  }
}
else
{
  /* No command-line arguments */
}
```

References:

> #### C11 (n1570), § 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> If they are declared, the parameters to the `main` function shall obey
>   the following constraints:
>
> — The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
>
> — `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
>
> — If the value of argc is
>   greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>   inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>   implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program
>   startup. The intent is to supply to the program information determined
>   prior to program startup from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If
>   the host environment is not capable of supplying strings with letters
>   in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation shall ensure that
>   the strings are received in lowercase.
>
> — If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the
>   program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the program
>   name is not available from the host environment. If the value of argc
>   is greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through
>   `argv[argc-1]` represent the program parameters.

Comment: So I can use "if(argv = -ah)"?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if (-ad)
```

you have to write something like

```
if (strcmp(argv[1],"-ad")==0)
```

Same for `if (-ah)`

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying to read command line arguments is wrong

Given

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
```

the first argument to your program (eg "-ad") will get stored in `argv[1]`.  You need to analyze that string to know what your program is expected to do.

[Here's](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html) a basic intro to argc and argv.  In real world programs there should be some protection as well: for example, the program should check whether it was actually called with a parameter by checking argc:

```
if (argc < 2) {
   printf("What do you want me to do?\n");
   return 3;
}
```

Alternatively - but try to get it working by handling the command line arguments manually at least once - you could delegate the entire command line handling to [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt).